# Cant set QBrush to QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, paint

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter painter(this);

    QBrush br;
    br.setColor(Qt::blue);
    painter.setBrush(br);

//    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));

    painter.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
```

This code doesn't work, blue rectangle is not drawn. But the commented line works fine. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart for setting color of the brush, you need to set style to the brush:

```
br.setStyle(Qt:SolidPattern);
```

If you check default constructor, and constructor signature you are using in the second example, you will see that above call is needed:

```
QBrush ( const QColor & color, Qt::BrushStyle style = Qt::SolidPattern )
```

> `QBrush::QBrush ()`
>
> Constructs a default black brush with the style Qt::NoBrush (i.e. this
>   brush will not fill shapes).

Answer (score 1):

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbrush.html

```
QBrush::QBrush ( Qt::BrushStyle style )
```

Constructs a black brush with the given style.

```
QBrush::QBrush ()
```

Constructs a default black brush with the style Qt::NoBrush (i.e. this brush will not fill shapes).

So

```
QBrush br = QBrush();
```

Should work to instantiate the object.

Comment: There is no need to create object and then to call copy constructor for `br`. Since `QBrush` is not POD structure, calling `QBrush br();` instead of `QBrush br;` will not make any difference.

Comment: I know, but seemed appropriate for the question. Cheers.